# How to get ride of ld: warning: object file was built for newer iOS version (12.0) than being linked (11.0)

Tags: ios, delphi, linker

Under delphi Alexandria, when I try to compile my ios app I receive this warning message from the linker :

> ld: warning: object file
> (.\Libraries\ios\facebook\FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework\ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(AppEvents+Internal.o))
> was built for newer iOS version (12.0) than being linked
> (11.0)

How to get ride of this error message or how to say to the linker the we target iOS 12 instead of iOS 11 ?

Answer (score 2):

I found, just add the -w to the linker option flag :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer, Stéphane